# Should I use !== or ==! when checking for not equal?

Tags: javascript

Should I use `!==` or `==!`? Both work, but what is the standard?

I enter "else" for both cases:

```
var x;
if (x !== undefined)
{
    alert("if..");
}
else
{
    alert('else..') // <--- here
}


var y;
if (y ==! undefined)
{
    alert("if..");
}
else
{
    alert('else..') // <--- here
}
```

Comment: `1 !== 2` is true, but `1 ==! 2` is false. `==!` is wrong-spaced `==` and `!`

Comment: Related: [The negation operator in JS](/q/66260351/4642212).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`==!` is not a comparison operator in Javascript. When you write `foo ==! bar`, you are actually writing `foo == !bar`, using the unary `!` negation operator and the binary `==` comparison operator. This probably does not do what you want it to:

```
> 'b' ==! 'a'
false
> 'b' !== 'a'
true
```

This happens to "work" in the particular situation you describe because `!undefined` evaluates to `true`, and `y == true` for undefined `y` is `false`, thus putting you on the `else` branch.

Comment: Also to add to your answer, `!==` also compares types, `!=` will compare values only. just like `===` and `==`

Comment: Okay I get it. That's also why my other if with two conditions was acting "weird". I will remember that thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (x !== undefined)
```

checks if x is not undefined, while

```
if (y ==! undefined)
```

negates `undefiend` (which returns `!undefined == true`) and then checks it for equality with `y`